# Magento: Remove a Shipping Method in Frontend

Tags: magento-1.5, magento

I'm currenty working on a shipping module extension that is used for an order-import script to set to every order the same shipping cost and shipping code.

Everythings works fine but the problem that is, that the shipping method is visible in frontend. I will release this extension later in magento connect, so its not pissible to edit frontend templates.

Does anyone know how to disable the carrier in frontend without disableing the module in backend or changeing the status to inactive and without editing templates? (e.g. a custom block that declines displaying)

Thanks to everyone! Mru

EDIT:
I've tried your tip like this, but it doesn't work:

```
    <blocks>
        <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <onepage_shipping_method_availible>XXX_XXX_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_availible>
            </rewrite>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
```

and created this class:

```
class XXX_XXX_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available
{

    public function getShippingRates()
    {
        if (empty($this->_rates)) {
            $this->getAddress()->collectShippingRates()->save();

            $groups = $this->getAddress()->getGroupedAllShippingRates();

            return $this->_rates = $groups;
        }
        return $this->_rates;
    }
}
```

(I don't know why it is not displayed correctly...)

Thanks for your held, MRu

EDIT2:
Sorry for being so stupid.. The above posted code would work if i were not unable to write 'availalbe'...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to overload the `Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available::getShippingRates()` method

Answer (score 2):

You can hide shipping method from front end with observer, write this code in `config.xml`

```
<frontend>
<events>
    <sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        <observers>
            <frontend_shipping_rates_sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
                <class>yourmodule/observer</class>
                <method>hideShippingMethods</method>                    
            </frontend_shipping_rates_sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
        </observers>                
    </sales_quote_collect_totals_before>
</events>
```

Second in `Observer.php` use this code

```
public function hideShippingMethods( Varien_Event_Observer $observer )
{
    if (Mage::getDesign()->getArea() ===   Mage_Core_Model_App_Area::AREA_FRONTEND)
    {
        $quote              = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
        $store              = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());
        $carriers           = Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers', $store);

        $hiddenMethodCode   = 'freeshipping'; 

        foreach ($carriers as $carrierCode => $carrierConfig) 
        {
            if( $carrierCode ==  $hiddenMethodCode )
            {
                $store->setConfig("carriers/{$carrierCode}/active", '0');
            }
        }
}
 }
```